# Grails template accessing database redundant

Tags: grails

I have a template

_template.gsp

```
<g:each in="${temp}" status="i" var="var">
    ${var}
</g:each>
```

I render this template in all my screens, How to do that?
 I did this and I find it very redundant

Controller

```
def action1(){
    def temp = Temp.list()
    [temp:temp]
}

def action2(){
    def temp = Temp.list()
    [temp:temp]
}
```

action1.gsp

```
<g:render template ="../template" />
```

action2.gsp

```
<g:render template ="../template" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off using `<g:include>` and including the results (which can still be a template) from your various GSPs.

For example:

```
def sharedAction() {
  def temp = Temp.list()
  render(template: 'templateNameHere', model: [temp: temp])
}
def action1() {
 ...
}
def action2() {
 ...
}
```

**action1.gsp and action2.gsp**

```
<g:include controller="theControllerName" action="sharedAction" />
```

**_templateNameHere.gsp**

```
<g:each in="${temp}" status="i" var="var">
    ${var}
</g:each>
```